# WinDbg analyzes minidump (!analyze -v), then what is NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE, INVALID_POINTER_READ...etc?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

I run WinDbg command `!analyze -v` on the minidump file, and WinDbg gave `PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS` as `NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE`. 
Some other minidump files gave `INVALID_POINTER_READ`. So what does they mean?

I tried to google for the definition, but wasn't able to find any official or detailed document. There should be a list of these problem class IDs, but there is not, weird.

So, does anyone knows any document for definitions of these IDs?
Or anyone could explain these IDs?

Thanks!

P.S. I'll give some explaination of myself below:
1. `NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE`: the `this` pointer is NULL.
2. `INVALID_POINTER_READ`: reading a pointer that has been `delete`-ed.
Not sure about these understanding though...

Comment: You better post a stack-trace so we can help you. without a trace I cant add anything to what you see.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the application crashed for memory access violation. The following link would give you more information on this:

Why does Software Crash #1 – The Access Violation 
[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chappell/archive/2005/01/12/351856.aspx)

You can retrieve more information regarding the crash reviewing the crashing call stack. Often this information leads to the root cause of the crash.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply!
i know it's due to access violation, but i do want to know more detail about those windbg symbols :)